# C program wont recognize space character

Tags: c, linux, ascii

I have a homework problem in C that is taking a user input of characters (only from a-z or a space) and return the ASCII value.  The code works fine if it is only the characters but when i try to enter a space it will not return the number 32.  Any help would be fantastic!

```
#include <stdio.h>

char buf[128];

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    buf[127] = 0;
    char *line = argv[1];
    int i;
    int j;
    i = 0;
    j = 126;
    while((line[i] >= 'a' && line[i] <= 'z') || (line[i] == ' ')){
        buf[j] = line[i];
        printf("%d", buf[j]);
        printf(" ");
        i++;
        j--;
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

There are no error messages.  For example if i enter the string 'hello' it returns '104 101 108 108 111' but if i enter 'hello guys' it also returns '104 101 108 108 111' and stops at the space character.

Comment: Your program uses only the command-line arguments instead of from `stdin` - is that intentional?

Comment: Your program works for me - except that shell doesn't pass single space to the program, it has to be quoted - like this: `./program " "`

Comment: @Dai yes this is intentional, i must use the command-line argument in this program unfortunately.

Comment: @aragaer that makes sense.  Thank you

Comment: regarding: `char *line = argv[1];`  Before accessing anything beyond `argv[0]` always check `argc` to assure the operator actually entered the expected command line parameters.  Also, when the command line include a space, your program will see it as two command line parameters (unless you wrap the whole parameter in "...")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not working because your program only uses command-line arguments (instead of reading from `stdin` which is what most C homeworks expect), and most shells will split command-line arguments by whitespace unless they're enclosed in quotes.

So this:

```
.\myprogram foo bar
```

Will be presented as:

```
argc == 3
argv[0] == "(path)/myprogram"
argv[1] == "foo"
argv[2] == "bar"
```

But this:

```
.\myprogram "foo bar"
```

Will be presented as:

```
argc == 2
argv[0] == "(path)/myprogram"
argv[1] == "foo bar"
```

Comment: That makes sense.  I will clarify with my teacher tomorrow if the input will contain quotes. Thank you!

Comment: @DylanT If the input will contain quotes, your shell will have a means of escaping them so they are visible to the program, for example, `bash` uses backslashes, for example `myprogram "foo\" bar"`.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your code, with respect to the space. However, the command line interpreter you are using (`cmd32.exe` on Windows?, `bash` on Linux?) considers the space as a parameter termination: if you write

```
yourprogram hello world
```

The "hello" goes to `argv[1]`, but "world" goes to `argv[2]`... and the space to nowhere.
Try with

```
yourprogram "hello world"
```

Using the quotes tells to the interpreter to consider the whole string "hello world" as a single parameter.

There are other things with your code:
You are filling a `buf` without doing anything with it. You are also filling it from the back, what is the reason for that?

Comment: the homework assignment makes me fill the buffer from the back and print it backwards (my best guess is that this is for practice, i am not sure why else he would make us do it like this).  And yes that makes sense, when i used the quotes it printed correctly. Thank you!

Comment: You are not printing backwards, you are filling buf backwards, but printing as you read, that is forward.

Comment: Right, my bad.  We are just supposed to fill the buffer backwards as a part of this assignment.  I am not too sure why it is a requirement.